# ASPXAUTH cookie duplicated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, session-cookies

Well I'm working on a WebApplication using FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName. I have this in the WebConfig:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms cookieless="UseCookies"
           name=".ASPXAUTH1" />
</authentication>
```

in code:

```
var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket))
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Domain = "." +host, // Ex- host = google.com (without www because we use subdomains)
    Secure = false

};
httpCookie.Expires = remember ? DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
```

When I log in to the  web app everything looks good:

[image]

the domain with the red arrow = .google.com

after a few seconds the second cookie appears with a different domain = www.google.com and Expires Date

[image]

I'm not using the RedirectToLoging Page Method.

Answer (score 0):

this was solved adding slidingExpiration property in webconfig

```
      <authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms cookieless="UseCookies" name=".ASPXAUTH"  slidingExpiration="false" />
```